# Angular 8 how to change the providers of material date picker according to selected material tab?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-providers

I have 2 material datepickers in my component. Each one of them is in different `mat-tab`.

The date picker of first tab should be as `MM/YYYY`, the second one should a normal date `DD/MM/YYYY`.

The first step of changing the value of datepicker to `MM/YYYY` is as follows:

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {

  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

And:

```
<mat-form-field>
      <input matInput formControlName="invoiceDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose the Month">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker startView="year" (yearSelected)="getSelectedYear($event)"
                    (monthSelected)="getSelectedMonth($event, picker)">
      </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

The main problem is when I added the second `datepicker` in my second `mat-tab`. Where the format `MM/YYYY` is used for all existing datepickers.

What I treid to do is to declare an exported variable as follows:

```
export let tab = 1;
```

And did two formats:

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {

  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

export const MY_FORMATS_RECEIPTS = {

  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

And at the providers part:

```
providers: [

    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: tab==0?MY_FORMATS:MY_FORMATS_RECEIPTS},
],
```

I am updating the `tab` on `mat-tab` click using:

```
<mat-tab-group (click)="getTab($event.which)">
```

And:

```
getTab(tab){
    tab = tab
}
```

I may be missed the concept of exported consts and variables, but this is the only solution I have and it didn't work.

If I've already declared tab as 0, it will take the first format, and when the component is loaded, and tab 1 is selected, nothing is changed.

Comment: hello :) did you find a solution to the problem ? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Ennar.ch unfortunately not.